# Get host from email string .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I need to get the host from an email address string.

In .net 4.x I did this

```
var email1 = "test@test.com";
var email2 = "test2@yea.test.com"
var email1Host = new MailAddress(email1).Host;
var email2Host = new MailAddress(email2).Host;
```

> email1Host prints "test.com"
>
> email2Host prints "yea.test.com"

But now i need only the "test.com" part in both examples.

.Net Standard library 1.6 doesnt have the System.Net.Mail class so I can't do this anymore.

Whats another way of accomplishing the same thing in .net core but I only need the test.com part

I know there is a System.Net.Mail-netcore nuget package, but I really want to avoid installing a nuget just for this

Edit: Sorry for the confusion I forgot to mention that I only need the test.com

More examples were requested

> @subdomain1.domain.co.uk => domain.co.uk
>
> @subdomain1.subdomain2.domain.co.uk => domain.co.uk
>
> @subdomain1.subdomain2.domain.com => domain.com
>
> @domain.co.uk => domain.co.uk
>
> @domain.com => domain.com

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result: [This dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/la8agr) yields `yea.test.com` for `email2Host`.

Comment: For TLD's, when previously working on SEO software, I found the best way to `Split` the URL without risking the TLD is by keeping a collection of all common TLD's. The problem with checking lengths after splitting by full-stops is that you can have any level of subdomains such as `subone.subtwo.subthree.test.co.uk`

Comment: Please add more examples of the desired output to your question. What should be the result for the addresses `...@a.co.uk`, `...@a.example.uk` and `@a.b.example` - and explain the *general rule* behind your desired output. I will remove my downvote once your question becomes clear.

Comment: @ColinM yea thats probably my only way to achieve what i want. Thanks

Comment: The regex solution below seems to do the trick

Comment: > An alternative is to use the System.Uri class and prefix the email with 'mailto'. [This answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759248/6865833) should be the accepted answer, regex usually have unaccounted for edge cases that you need to take care of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using String Split and Regex,

```
    var email1 = "test@test.com";
    var email2 = "test2@yea.test.co.uk";
    var email1Host = email1.Split('@')[1];
    var email2Host = email2.Split('@')[1];


    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^.]*\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?$");
    Match match = regex.Match(email1Host);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email Host1: "+match.Value);
    }

    match = regex.Match(email2Host);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email Host2: "+match.Value);
    }
```

**Update**: Using regex to get the Domain name

Comment: email2Host returns yea.test.com.. I only need the test.com part.

Comment: @user56567675: The code snippet in your question *also* returns `yea.test.com`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/la8agr

Comment: Yep. Like @juunas said it might not be so simple to find just the TLD as there are exceptions.

Comment: So this will fail if you work with 2-3 character domains/subdomains, but thats not my case so I will accept this answer.

Comment: @user56567675 yep. It'll fail then. It'll also fail for new domain extensions  like example.online, example.guru, etc... where the extension is greater than 3 characters. The regex can be modified with the exceptions though.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the `System.Uri` class and prefix the email with 'mailto'.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string email = "test@test.com";
        string emailTwo = "test2@subdomain.host.com";

        Uri uri = new Uri($"mailto:{email}");
        Uri uriTwo = new Uri($"mailto:{emailTwo}");

        string emailOneHost = uri.Host;
        string emailTwoHost = uriTwo.Host;

        Console.WriteLine(emailOneHost); // test.com
        Console.WriteLine(emailTwoHost); // subdomain.host.com

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: i just need the host.com not subdomain

Comment: This is something you failed to mention in the original post, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a bit of C# should do the trick:

```
string email = "test@test.com";
int indexOfAt = email.IndexOf('@');
//You do need to check the index is within the string
if (indexOfAt >= 0 && indexOfAt < email.Length - 1)
{
    string host = email.Substring(indexOfAt + 1);
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that is true! If you want host.com from that then it's not quite so simple :( There are domains like host.co.uk which have three parts so it's pretty hard to make something that works very generically for that.